# Android Chrome Password Pop-up

Tags: chrome-for-android, password, popup

Does anyone know how to eliminate this annoying pop-up (see screenshot) in Chrome that has a separate window for passwords? I know it can be done but I can't find it and any every time I search for it, the result is only how to resolve the check your passwords compromised passwords pop up from chrome. Thanks in advance.

[image: Annoying pop-up]

Comment: It is Chrome's password manager... If you don't want it, disable it. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606

Comment: I don't want to disable the password feature, I just don't want the pop-up. An older version of Chrome had the fields just filled in rather than as a separate pop up. It's just another annoying "fix" and there's a way to disable it and go back to the old way but I just haven't found it. I had fixed it on a previous phone and cannot find the way to fix it again.

Comment: Chrome constantly changes.  This was one of the recent changes to Chrome.  The only way to disable the popup would be to delete the saved password for that particular website